# How to deal with new iMac sizes for responsive web design?

Tags: responsive-design, screen-resolution

There's a lot that has been written about media queries for to keep mobile first in mind, however, I have read very little about optimizing for larger screens (TV) and particularly, the new iMac. The dimensions here are much larger. What's the standard that people are using that work for small (mobile), medium (tablet), and desktop (from like a 13" inch MacBook pro to a large iMac)?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of comments.

Mobile first doesn't exclude larger devices. Think of it as starting with a basic design for small screen mobile devices and then adding more features and building out the design as you move up through smartphones, laptops and desktop devices.

It doesn't have to be overly complicated for larger viewports. Think about increasing font and image sizes, and you'll have enough horizontal space that you could add an extra column or other elements if you need to.

With media queries and responsive design, you are typically looking at pixels, e.g. is the window or viewport of the user greater than 960 pixels wide. Don't confuse pixels with the physical size on a screen, pixel size can vary widely between different devices.